# Google maps and google location autocomplete clashing

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-maps-api-3

Am displaying a google map and below it have a text input where am using google's places autocomplete. I'm having problem where either the map is displayed or the autocomplete works, but am not able to get both working together :(

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HaDbR/11/
The map there works fine but the text box autocomplete ain't.

http://jsfiddle.net/HaDbR/12/
The location autocomplete works, but map ain't.

I have a strong hunch am going wrong with the external Google Maps API JS source am including in the script section, but my brain is fried and am not able to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
createMap();
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function() { }
```

...that fixed it for me.